# Use list comprehension to replace specific values in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples of floats like this one:

`my_list = [(1.1, 6.6, 3.3), (4.4, 5.5, 9.9)]`

However, I need to set a limit for my values such that no value in any of the tuples exceeds a limit. For the sake of this example let's say that `limit = 6.`.

I am looking for a simple list comprehension solution, but everything I have tried so far has failed.

For example:
`new_list = [ y for x in my_list if y <= limit for y in x ]`

results in an "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment".

Using nested for loops I can reach a solution:

```
my_new_list = []                                                                                                     

for my_tuple in my_list:  
    new_tuple = [] 
    for i, value in enumerate(my_tuple): 
        if value > limit: 
            value = limit 
        new_tuple.append(value) 
     my_new_list.append(new_tuple)
```

But I am looking for a simple list comprehension solution.

Edit: This has been solved, but to clarify, since there was some ambiguity in the question, I was hoping to keep the form of the list the same and replace any values over the limit, with that limit. This is the output I was looking for: [(1.1, 6., 3.3), (4.4, 5.5, 6.)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect this is what you’re looking for? This reproduces the same format as the input, just capping all values at the limit.

```
[tuple(min(i, limit) for i in t) for t in my_list]
```

Comment: Yes! This exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You asked for list comprehension, so you just loop over tuples inside a list comprehension, with an inner loop over values, and use `min`:

```
my_list = [(1.1, 6.6, 3.3), (4.4, 5.5, 9.9)]
limit = 6.

print([tuple(min(v, limit) for v in t) for t in my_list])
```

This gives:

```
[(1.1, 6., 3.3), (4.4, 5.5, 6.)]
```

Actually the inner loop is in the form of a generator comprehension, but the `tuple()` will iterate over this and convert it into a tuple.

Obviously this creates new tuples rather than attempting to modify the existing ones, because tuples are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Check This just little change in your code

`limit=6`

`my_list = [(1.1, 6.6, 3.3), (4.4, 5.5, 9.9)]`

`[y for x in my_list for y in x if y<=limit ]`

Comment: This is a good solution for filtering out the values above the limit. I *think* in fact that the question is asking about setting them to the limit rather than removing them, based on the OP's code, although their description is a bit ambiguous.